# Is iTunes freezing related to 32 or 64 bit version problem?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, 32-bit, itunes-10

iTunes is nearly unusable for me, and freezes so many times it seems to be standard behavior.

When I opened taskmgr this time I notice there are these running [image: itunes services and apps]

64 bit iTunes is installed, but I do know that the update has detected things wrong before and downloaded the wrong update and then failed. Now I have no idea what is actually installed, although I have a 64 bit machine.

Do I have a version conflict or a mess of intermixed applications causing the instability I am seeing?
I have gotten to HATE iTunes, and have to KILL it regularly.

Can anyone enlighten me as to whether these versions are part of the problem? And what is the least difficult process to set things right?

If there were a simple alternative, I would dump iTunes completely, but have too much expecting it to work, so I would rather fix it.